# Joining onto a subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

I have the follwing SQL query (It get's the largest of a certain column per group, with 3 things to group by):

```
select p1.Name, p1.nvr, p1.Arch, d1.repo, p1.Date
from Packages as p1 inner join
    Distribution as d1
    on p1.rpm_id = d1.rpm_id inner join (
        select Name, Arch, repo, max(Date) as Date
        from Packages inner join Distribution
            on Packages.rpm_id = Distribution.rpm_id
        where Name like 'p%' and repo not like '%staging'
        group by Name, Arch, repo
    ) as sq
    on p1.Name = sq.Name and p1.Arch = sq.Arch and d1.repo = sq.repo and p1.Date = sq.Date
    order by p1.nvr
```

And I'm trying to convert it to SQLAlchemy. This is what I have so far:

```
p1 = aliased(Packages)
d1 = aliased(Distribution)
sq = session.\
        query(
            Packages.Name,
            Packages.Arch,
            Distribution.repo,
            func.max(Packages.Date).\
                                        label('Date')).\
        select_from(
            Packages).\
        join(
            Distribution).\
        filter(
            queryfilter).\
        filter(
            not_(Distribution.repo.\
                                    like('%staging'))).\
        group_by(
            Packages.Name,
            Packages.Arch,
            Distribution.repo).subquery()

result = session.\
            query(
                p1, d1.repo).\
            select_from(
                p1).\
            join(
                d1).\
            join(
                sq,
                p1.Name==sq.c.Name,
                p1.Arch==sq.c.Arch,
                d1.repo==sq.c.repo,
                p1.Date==sq.c.Date).\
            order_by(p1.nvr).all()
```

The problem arises when I do the join on the subquery. I get an error that states that there is no from clause to join from. This is strange because I specify one right after the subquery in the join funciton as an argument. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Perhaps I need to alias something and do a select_from again?

EDIT: Exact error

```
Could not find a FROM clause to join from. Tried joining to SELECT "Packages"."Name", "Packages"."Arch", "Distribution".repo, max("Packages"."Date") AS "Date" FROM "Packages" JOIN "Distribution" ON "Packages".rpm_id = "Distribution".rpm_id WHERE "Packages"."Name" LIKE :Name_1 AND "Distribution".repo NOT LIKE :repo_1 GROUP BY "Packages"."Name", "Packages"."Arch", "Distribution".repo, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'Join object on %(139953254400272 Packages)s(139953254400272) and %(139953256322768 Distribution)s(139953256322768)' and '%(139953257005520 anon)s'.
```

It's trying to join, but it says it doesn't know where to make the join. Is there something wrong with my syntax? I think it's correct based on what's in the join function.

Comment: Try to alias the subquery and also try to work with literal join conditions. You might need to expirement a bit here.

Comment: How can I use literal join conditions? What do you mean by that. I've also updated my post with the specific error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently you need to add an `and_()` around multiple join conditions.

```
join(
    sq,
    and_(p1.Name==sq.c.Name,
    p1.Arch==sq.c.Arch,
    d1.repo==sq.c.repo,
    p1.Date==sq.c.Date)).\
```

Comment: What if you wanted attributes from the subquery in the result.  How would you write that?